# how to identity a click out of the form and 1 more question

Tags: c#

i want to build a simple program which help you selecting pictures.
if you have lot of picture and you want to choose some of them then you see them 1 by 1 and when you see a picture you would lik to save on other folder on your pcyou just press a button ,lets say f5 and the program copy the phtot from the path you looking at to the destiny folder.

for that program i need to ask how to know if someone pressed f5 out of the form area and how to know in which path the user looking at.(i want to build it for myself atm so if its help i look with microsoft office picture manager)

about the clicking i search a little and get something named global clicking and hooks which i dont understand so much and about identify the path i have no idea .
tyvm for help:)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow the rest -- but if you want to capture the keypress event, simply add an event handler for KeyPress and determine if the pressed key is equal to the F5 button by using the Keys constants.

Comment: Here is the MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a project on Code Project that does exactly what you need :)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx

Comment: tyvm :)
any chance you know anything about my other question?

the question: when i search photos in microsoft office picture manager i would like to save the currect photo that the user is watching if he press f5?
and ty again

Comment: That would require some nasty hacking i believe. You would have to "look" into the memory being used by Picture Manager, and figure out the current picture. Not pretty. Unless, of course, Picture Manager is Extensible, which i doubt :-\

Answer (score 0):

The key press event wont work with the following ([Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar(VS.80).aspx)):

- TAB
- INSERT
- DELETE
- HOME
- END
- PAGE UP
- PAGE DOWN
- F1-F2
- ALT
- Arrow keys

**Note:** I think there is a typo on the page and the F1-F2 really should be F1-F12.

When you decide the key for your on key press event for the form area you are talking about it will look like this:

```
private void Form_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.KeyChar == [keypressvalue])
  {
     //do your copy logic
  }
}
```

[keypressvalue] will be the code for F5 if you choose to use this. I have found a mix of values for this (i could not get my test keypress event to pick up the F5 event, hence my note above) so i recommend running the event once with a brake point, inspecting the code, then brake and update your code, then test your logic.

Like the rest i'm not really sure what you want your custom logic to do.

Clairifcation: I'm trying to understand your question, so what you want is: When in Microsoft Picture Manager when you press F5 you want the image that is currently being viewed to be moved to a particular directory? Now if you are writing your own picture viewer and move software then i think we can help if it is the above i'm not really sure you can do that.